# Local conversion of model

Tags: autodesk-forge

In addition to "Model Derivative", is there any tool provided to be installed locally on our desktop to convert models efficiently?
Or is there any plan to do it from autodesk forge side?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately our Model Derivative service does not support local/on-premise deployment. Given the complex and resource demanding nature of this service technically it'd be extremely challenging for desktop grade systems to run efficiently.

There's no plan in the foreseeable future to support private deployment to any on-premise/third party platform either - again the technical complexity and licensing complications would be a major hindrance.

But that shouldn't stop you from coming up with your own locally hosted app to facilitate the translation - see our extractor sample [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/) for inspiration.